# How to change the return command to something similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using the following code and since I'm using promises I want to avoid the last return statement(because it is a bit confusing since I use chaining), how should I do that ?

This is the code which is working OK

```
return $.get('users.json', null, null, 'json')
    .then(function (response) {

        return response.filter(function (user) {
            return user.id === 4;
        })[0];

    })
```

I want to avoid the last return which is `return user.id === 4;` and write it in different way, how should I do that ?

I've tried with

```
if (user.id === 4){
    exit
}
```

which is not working,any other idea?

Comment: What do you perceive to be wrong with your code currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to return `true` or `false` for the `.filter`...
so your other way its just to return false or true youre self..

```
if (user.id === 4){ 
   return false; //or ture what ever you want..
}
```

but i dont understand why you change it... you could add some coments if its not clear to read.

Comment: Thanks reyaner,My question is there is a way to avoid the return keyword,write it diff without return in JS?

Comment: No. The `filter` method depends on the return value from the function you pass it, so you need it to return a value.